# Array of Strings Ignores index 0 while initializing it in a for loop

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexing

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = input.nextInt();
        String[] strArr = new String[num];
        arrStrMaker(strArr);
    }

    public static void arrStrMaker(String[] arr){
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("String for index ["+i+"]");
            arr[i] = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
3
String for index [0]

String for index [1]
```

*Notice how it ignores completely the input in index 0 and "inserts" nothing into index 0*

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 3;
        String[] strArr = new String[num];
        arrStrMaker(strArr);
    }

    public static void arrStrMaker(String[] arr){
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("String for index ["+i+"]");
            arr[i] = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

output : 
`String for index [0]`

*Notice how it didnt ignore index 0 and waits for a input.

what seems to be the problem?
when i use `int num = input.nextInt();` ignores index 0.
when i use `int num = 3;` waits for input at index 0.

Comment: try `int num = input.nextInt(); input.nextLine();`

Answer (score 0):

`nextLine` and `nextInt` (in fact, `nextLine` and any other `next-anything` call that isn't `nextLine`) interact weirdly. I suggest you do this:

```
`input.useDelimiter("\r?\n");`
```

immediately after creating the scanner (`new Scanner(...)`), everytime you make scanners, and then use `next()` instead of `nextLine()`. This sets the 'delimiter' to newlines only, so now your scanner will feed you 1 token every time the user hits enter; that's usually what you want from scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Try skipping the `newLine` character from your input as below:

```
arr[i] = input.nextLine();
input.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
```

Comment: Re [this proposed edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24972310) please don't change to code format just because a word/name appears in code or output. Please make substantive changes when others must review. Please remove thanks, pleading etc when doing that.

Comment: @philipxy, thanks for pointing out. I believe I got what you are saying. But, not sure what to do with the post.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by not sure what to do. Could you rephrase? You can look at how I edited the post (and my comments on it relevant to that) (and its edit history) via the title link at the link I gave above.